# Fix TypeError in Keras class - how to cast Keras.Sequential to Layer class so it can be part of a Keras.Model instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code, and I am getting a TypeError. My guess is that I am making a `Keras.Model` part of a, well, `Keras.Model` when I should have been using `Layer` instead. Long story short, how can I cast the `Keras.Sequential` object that `mlp` returns so that when I construct an instance of `SumNet`, I don't get:

```
raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: input_1 Placeholder FLOAT32(<tile.Value SymbolicDim UINT64()>, 5)
 :
```

**EDIT:** It needs to be a Keras API-only way due to the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156573/amd-plaidml-vs-cpu-tensorflow-unexpected-results). Perhaps, the function `mlp` needs to be rewritten so it returns a type `Layer` not `Model` somehow.

The code is here:

```
def mlp(size_in, size_out, act=layers.ReLU):
    return keras.Sequential([layers.Input(shape=(size_in,)),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer1'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer2'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer3'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(size_out, name='layer4')])


class SumNet(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SumNet, self).__init__()

        ########################################################
        # The same inductive bias as above!
        self.g = mlp(5, 1)
        self.f = mlp(1, 1)

    def call(self, x):
        y_i = self.g(x)[:, :, 0]
        y = keras.backend.sum(y_i, axis=1, keepdims=True) / y_i.shape[1]
        z = self.f(y)
        return z[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

After much discussion with AloneTogether I figured out a way to rewrite the `mlp` function so that it plays nice with the subclassed model. Apparently, the `Sequential` module does not cast well.

Here is the rewritten function:

```
def mlp2(size_in, size_out):
    hidden = 128
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(size_in,))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer1', activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer2', activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer3', activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(size_out, name='layer4', activation='relu')(x)
    m = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return m
```